# Put bit int value into bitarray

Tags: python, bitstring

How do you input an int value into a bitarray without it interpreting such as decimal, so that for example:

```
intvalue = 101
```

keeps the same digits even after conversion?

```
strvalue = bitstring.BitArray(intvalue)
strvalue == 101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prefix it with `0b` (just as you can prefix a hexadecimal integer with `0x`):

```
print(0b101)  # 5
```

that is how you can input an integer in binary form (independent of `bitarray`). see e.g. [PEP-3127](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/).